# OpenGL rendering/updating loop issues

Tags: opengl

I'm wondering how e.g. graphic (/game) engines do their job with lot's of heterogeneous data while a customized simple rendering loop turns into a nightmare when you have some small changes.

Example:

First, let's say we have some blocks in our scene.

1. Graphic-Engine: create cubes and move them
2. Customized: create cube template for vertices, normals, etc. copy and translate them to the position and copy e.g. in a vbo. One glDraw* call does the job.

Second, some weird logic. We want block 1, 4, 7, ... to rotate on x-axis, 2, 5, 8, ... on y-axis and 3, 6, 9 on z-axis with a rotation speed linear to the camera distance.

1. Graphic-Engine: manipulating object's matrix and it works
2. Customized: (I think) per object glDraw* call with changing model-matrix uniform is not a good idea, so a translation matrix should be something like an attribute? I have to update them every frame.

Third, a block should disappear if the distance to the camera is lower than any const value Q.

1. Graphic-Engine: if (object.distance(camera) < Q) scene.drop(object);
2. Customized: (I think) our vbo is invalid and we have to recreate it?

Again to the very first sentence: it feels like engines do those manipulations for free, while we have to rethink how to provide and update data. And while we do so, the engine (might, but I actually don't know) say: 'update whatever you want, at least I'm going to send all matrizes'.

Another Example: What about a voxel-based world (e.g. Minecraft) where we only draw the visible surface, and we are able to throw a bomb and destroy many voxels. If the world's view data is in one huge buffer we only have one glDraw*-call but have to recreate the buffer every time then. If there are smaller chunks, we have many glDraw*-calls and also have to manipulate buffers, which are smaller.

So is it a good deal to send let's say 10MB of buffer update data instead of 2 gl*-calls with 1MB? How many updates are okay? Should a rendering loop deal with lazy updates?

I'm searching for a guide what a 60fps application should be able to update/draw per frame to get a feeling of what is possible. For my tests, every optimization try is another bottleneck.

And I don't want those tutorials which says: hey there is a new cool gl*Instance call which is super-fast, buuuuut you have to check if your gpu supports it. Well, I also rather consider this an optimization than a meaningful implementation at first.

Do you have any ideas, sources, best practices or rule of thumb how a rendering/updating routine best play together?

My questions are all nearly the same:

- How many updates per frame are okay on today's hardware?
- Can I lazy-load data to have it after a few frames, but without freezing my application
- Do I have to do small updates and profile my loop if there are some microseconds left till next rendering?
- Maybe I should implement a real-time profiler which gets a feeling over time, how expensive updates are and can determine the amount of updates per frame?

Thank you.

Comment: Well, your customized rendering loop can do exactly the same as a generic graphic's engine one. But because it's customized it can actually be optimized for your specific case, by, e.g., not storing the scene graph in an explicit data structure and evaluating the matrices etc.. in-place rather than tossing them around in memory.

Comment: Although I find the question very interesting, I would not know where to start with an answer since it would require a rather extensive length. Could you break it down to a question that can be answered with realistic effort?

Comment: @BDL the focus is on how to handle updates without freezing your application. Instead of trying it out it would be nice, if someone could say: "on today's hardware it should be no problem to have a worst-case of 50k vertices updates." Or maybe he says "20 gl* Buffer update calls with not more than 100MB are okay". How would one setup a scene with lot's of vertices which might change every few seconds? Is there a lazy loading strategy in opengl, that I can say: please update 50k vertices, but I need not be for the next frame (don't freeze).

Comment: I've added some questions above and although only one question is allowed, the concern is always the same. I don't understand the close votes of my entry? What's the problem of it?

Answer (score 3):

It's unclear how any of your questions relate to your "graphics engines" vs "customized" examples. All the updates you do with a "graphics engines" are translated to those OpenGL calls in the end.

In brief:

> How many updates per frame are okay on today's hardware?

Today's PCIe bandwidth is huge (can go as high as 30 GB/s). However, to utilize it in its entirety you have to reduce the number transactions via consolidating OpenGL calls. The exact number of updates entirely depends on the hardware, drivers, and the way you use them, and graphics hardware **is diverse**.

This is the kind of answer you didn't want to hear, but unfortunately you have to face the truth: to reduce the number of OpenGL calls you have to use the newer version APIs. E.g. instead of setting each uniform individually you are better to submit a bunch of them through uniform shader buffer objects. Instead of submitting each MVP of each model individually, it's better to use instanced rendering. And so on.

An even more radical approach would be to move to a lower-level (and newer) API, i.e. Vulkan, which aims to solve exactly this problem: the cost of submitting work to the GPU.

> Can I lazy-load data to have it after a few frames, but without freezing my application

Yes, you can upload buffer objects asynchronously. See [Buffer Object Streaming](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming) for details.

> Do I have to do small updates and profile my loop if there are some microseconds left till next rendering?
>
> Maybe I should implement a real-time profiler which gets a feeling over time, how expensive updates are and can determine the amount of updates per frame?

You don't need any of these if you do it asynchronously.